# Unable to install R-base. Tried all methods listed here and even reinstalled Ubuntu

Tags: apt, dependencies

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-recommended (= 3.5.3.20190412-1~ubuntu18.04.1~ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have reinstalled Ubuntu and tried cleaning up the broken packages. Still it shows the same error.

Output of `apt-cache policy r-base`:

```
r-base:
 Installed: (none)
 Candidate: 3.5.3.20190412-1~ubuntu18.04.1~ppa1
 Version table:
    3.5.3.20190412-1~ubuntu18.04.1~ppa1 500
       500 ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rdev/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages 
       500 ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rdev/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
    3.4.4-1ubuntu1 500 
       500 in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages 
       500 in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
```

Comment: I've added that as answer. If you found that helpfu, consider accepting that by clicking on ✔. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From comments:

- Remove [Michael Rutter's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~marutter)

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:marutter/rdev
  ```
- Try installing R again from Ubuntu's official repository

  ```
  sudo apt install r-base
  ```